# Change the Sequence of JqGrid Columns

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I wanted to change the grid column sequence dynamically. For e.g. By default the grid will be loaded in LoginId, FirstName and LastName sequence. Based on some condition, I need to change the FirstName and LastName sequence.

Is there any way I can do this?

I tried doing like:

```
{name:'UserName',index:'UserName',width:82,sortable:false},
if(true)
{
   {name:'FirstName',index:'FirstName',width:65,sortable:false},
   {name:'LastName',index:'LastName',width:65,sortable:false},
}
else
{
   {name:'LastName',index:'LastName',width:65,sortable:false},
   {name:'FirstName',index:'FirstName',width:65,sortable:false},   
}
```

but I could not get this work.

Comment: If I want to change the position of the Add , Update and Delete icons then how can I do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `remapColumns` function to do this. In the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) of the function you will find the example which seems to be wrong, because indexes in the permutation array seem to be 1-based and not 0-based. Try to use:

```
$("#list").remapColumns([1,3,2],true,false);
```

or

```
$("#list").remapColumns([1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9],true,false);
```

if you want to change the order of the second and third from the total 9 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using jqGrid  3.5.3 version library. Is this feature available in this version?

Comment: @Amar: I have no idea. Is it now work? You should post a code example which can reproduce your problem. I am only a user and not a developer of jqGrid. On the page http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:change#jqgrid_3.7.2_changes_and_fixes there are no information about changes in `remapColumns`, but I am not sure. It seems to me there are some bug fixes in the time. Why you don't download from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 and use the last version of jqGrid?

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the quick reply. I checked for the remapColumns method and it is not present in the 3.5.3 version. I am upgrading my jqgrid to latest version now. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Amar: You welcome! I recommend you to test the program after the usage of `remapColumns` more carefull. I had seen a lot of bugs in the `columnChooser` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) which use `remapColumns`. If you will find a new bug post it to the http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/.

Comment: I've playing around with `remapColumns` lately. In jQGrid 4.1.2, the permutation is really 0-based. But note that rownumber (rn), multiselect checkbox (cb) and other hidden columns are also counted. So when you do the permutation, remember to include these columns.

Comment: @jackysee: Yes, the index in `remapColumns` is just the index in the `colModel` which contain all helper columns. The `colModel` can have up to tree helper columns at the first places: 'rn' (`rownumbers: true`), 'cb' (`multiselect: true`) and 'subgrid' (`subGrid: true`) and some columns at the end in case of treegrid (like `level`, `isLeaf`, `expanded` and so on). You can calculate easy get the index of the column (`getColumnIndexByName` function from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575192/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-row-based-on-row-cell-value-by-column-name/6575634#6575634)

Comment: @frabiacca: Sorry, but I don't full understand your question. Form editing uses just the same order of the fields as the current order in `colModel`. If you would use `recreateForm: true` (my default setting) the form will be created in the new order.