# jqgrid conditional formatting.

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to jqgrid using after insert row. However nothing seems to be happening. I've used afterInsertRow in the past and it's worked. Any suggestions?

```
jQuery("#gridDevicePlan").jqGrid
    ({ 
        url:'/dashboard/summarydeviceplans', 
        datatype: "json", 
        colNames:['Temporal','Short Name','Customer', 'Start', 'End', 'Duration', 'Device Count'], 
        colModel:[  {name:'Temporal',index:'Temporal'},
                    {name:'ShortName',index:'ShortName'},
                    {name:'Customer',index:'Customer'},
                    {name:'DateStart',index:'DateStart',formatter:'date', formatoptions:{srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat:'m/d/Y H:i'}},
                    {name:'DateStop',index:'DateStop',formatter:'date', formatoptions:{srcformat:'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat:'m/d/Y H:i'}}, 
                    {name:'Duration',index:'Duration'},
                    {name:'DeviceCount',index:'DeviceCount'}
                    ],
        //multiselect: true,  
        rowNum:10, 
        rowList:[10,50,100,300],
        //autowidth: true,
        autowidth: true,
        height: 'auto', 
        pager: '#pagerDevicePlan', 
        sortname: 'ShortName,Customer,DateStart', 
        mtype: "POST", 
        editurl:'/deviceplan/abort',   
        postData:{'deviceIDs[]':$('#device').val(), 
                  'timezone':<?="'".$this->criteria['timezone']."'"?>,
                  'gmtStartDate':<?="'".$this->criteria['gmtStartDate']."'"?>,
                  'gmtStopDate':<?="'".$this->criteria['gmtStopDate']."'"?>           
                 },
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        grouping: true,
        caption:false, 
        afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData) {  //set condiditonal formatting
            alert(aData.Temporal);
            if(aData.Temporal != 'Current'){
             $("#"+rowid).addClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        } 
    }); 
    jQuery("#gridDevicePlan").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDevicePlan',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Comment: never-mind, took of grouping, and it works.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you **never use `afterInsertRow`**. Instead of that you should always use `gridview: true` parameter which increase performance of jqGrid without any disadvantages. If you use `gridview: true` the filling of the grid body will be first constructed as a string represented the corresponding HTML fragment and then the body will be placed on the page as one operation. You can't use `gridview: true` together with `afterInsertRow`. If you use `afterInsertRow` the rows of the grid will be placed on the page sequentially and then will be called `afterInsertRow` after every row adding. Placing of any element of the page require that the web browser need to **recalculate all position of all elements on the page**. Which make the filling of the grid much slowly.

What you should to do instead is to enumerate the grid rows inside of `loadComplete` and add "ui-state-error" class to some rows of the grid. By the way the call `$("#"+rowid).addClass("ui-state-error");` is also ineffective in the loop. The `<table>` DOM element (`jQuery("#gridDevicePlan")[0]` or `this` inside of `loadComplete`) has [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) property which are very effective for row enumeration. It you do have to find table/grid row by rowid you can use another DOM method `namedItem` of the [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp). It find the row in the grid more effectively.

The solution of your main question you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575192/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-row-based-on-row-cell-value-by-column-name/6575634#6575634). The corresponding [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridChangeRowBackgroundBasedOnCheckboxes.htm) work very quickly even if the grid has relatively many rows.