# jqGrid Custom Formatter Set Cell wont work with options.rowId

Tags: jqgrid, cell, formatter

Ive been through all the posts, finally got setCell to work with hardcoded values, but not using the options.rowId.

```
 function StatusFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if (cellvalue == 'C'){
        jQuery("#list").setCell(options.rowId , 'SOORDLINE', '', { color: 'red' });
        jQuery("#list").setCell("[2.000]", 'SOORDLINE', '', { color: 'red' });
        jQuery("#list").setCell('[2.000]', 'SOREQDATE', '', { color: 'red' });
        jQuery("#list").setCell(options.rowId, 'SOPRICE', '', { color: 'red' });
    }
    return cellvalue;
    };
```

The FIRST and LAST lines dont work, but the 2 with the hardcoded rowId DO work. I inspected what comes back in the option.rowId and they are the same as the hardcoded values, (just different depending on the row of course. What am I missing? Please help. I dont see any difference between the lines, or values.

EDITED-

I tried the answer, and it seems to be what I need. I tried the following

```
      { name: 'SOORDLINE', index: 'SOORDLINE', width: 25, search: false ,celattr: function () { return ' style="color: red"'; }
},
```

To aleast make them all red before I dove into the logic, and it didnt do anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) in *absolute wrong way*. The goal of the custom formatter to to provide HTML fragment to fill the content of the cells in the corresponding column. So the `StatusFormatter` will be called *before* the row with the id equal to `options.rowId` will be created. Moreover for performance purpose one use typically `gridview: true`. in the case the whole content of the grid (the whole body of the grid) will be constructed first as string and only after that will be placed in the grid body in one operation. It improve the performance because after placing of any element web browser have to recalculate position of all other elements on the page.

If you want to set text color on the `SOORDLINE` cell you should `cellattr` instead:

```
celattr: function () { return ' style="color: red"'; }
```

The `celattr` can be used also in the form `celattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject) {...}` and you can test the property of `rawObject` which represent of the values for any column and return the cell style based on the cell value.

Alternatively you can enumerate the rows inside of `loadComplete` and set the style on `<tr>` element instead of setting the same styles for every row. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575634/315935) as an example.

Comment: NOTE: I did get it to work, your example only had on 'l' in cellattr, instead of 2, I looked through the source in the example and saw the difference.

Comment: This solution didnt seem to work when grouping is ON. And when you sort, the attribut, being the color in this example goes away.

Comment: I fixed the color issue by turning loadonce off I guess the attributes dont carry over when the rows get shuffled, and the celattr doesnt get re-implemented. just a guess.

Comment: @D-S: The problem is that you included too few information in the text of your question. You should always include definition of jqGrid. At least full `colModel` and the value of `datatype` and `loadonce` parameters. In case of the usage of custom formatter you should always include test JSON or XML data which you use. Having the information I could show you how to use `cellattr` and custom `formatter` in your case. It will work together with `loadonce: true`