# jqgrid form editing: invert column order

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i've been using jqgrid widely (and successfully) on my asp.net web application.

Is it possible to invert column order in form editing?
ie: colmodel shows

COLUMN A
COLUMN B
COLUMN C

I'd like to show something similar to:

COLUMN A
COLUMN C
COLUMN B

when user click the edit icon and enter the form editing dialog.

**EDIT**: i've read the remapColumns function exist ([check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665692/change-the-sequence-of-jqgrid-columns)). Is it possible to use it on form editing?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of the column order with respect of the following simple code

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var i, l, $tinfo = $form.find('tr.tinfo'),
        $trFormData = $form.find('tr.FormData');
    for (i = 1, l = $trFormData.length; i < l; i++) {
        $tinfo.after($trFormData[i]);
    }
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ReverceOrderOfColumnsInFormEditing.htm). As the result you will get

[image]

instead of default form

[image]

Comment: oleg, i'm sorry, but this is not what I'm looking for. It seems to me that you just inverted column order; I'd like to recreate form field order instead. You wrote me to use recreateForm:true yesterday, i've been searching for an example since that instant :(

Comment: @frabiacca: You asked me one comment my about the usage of `remapColumns`. If you change the order of columns it's important to use [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6971820/315935) an example) to have the current order of columns. Your current question is "jqgrid form editing: invert column order". It's not depend from the usage of `columnChooser`, `reorderColumn` and so on. If there are some other additional steps where you need another order of the fields in the form dialog - please describe

Comment: hey oleg, i find that formoptions contains rowpos attribute, that is exactly what i was looking for ;)

Comment: @frabiacca: OK! I just still not full understand your question. If you really have *tree* columns like COLUMN A COLUMN B COLUMN C and you want *to specify* the position of *one column* you can good use `rowpos`. So if you need *to specify* the row where the field for the column will be placed the `rowpos` is the best way, but you can't use the option *to invert* the column order because if you would modify `colModel` and insert one more column you will have to modify **all** `rowpos` values all columns. So it was just misunderstanding of your requirements.

Comment: @frabiacca: In any way it's fine that your problem is solved!